# How should I restore a backup of my user account from a .dmg?

Tags: macos, time-machine, hard-drive, backup

I have on my external hard drive a `.dmg` which is a backup from when my internal hardrive was breaking.

Fixing the (internal) hard drive I then went on to erase it. And reinstall OSX in the process it asked me if I had any time machine backups. Which I do (on the same external) hard drive but it was very out of date.

What I want to know is; How can I get all the data back from the .dmg that I backed up (and have now fixed using DiskWarrior)?

---

Should I just drag and drop the User folder? What would you reccomend?

Comment: What is the size of your user folder? and the size of the external disk?

Comment: external disk 1 tb.  User on external 404gb

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying sorry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Copy the user folder into /Users
2. Make a user with the same short name as the user that you copied in using the Users & Groups preference pane. This should prompt you to link the new user to the home folder that you copied in.

   <sup>Note: Don't log in as that user yet.</sup>
3. Reset the new user's ACLs using the ACL tool on the Recovery HD.

   1. Boot into the Recovery HD using ⌘R.
   2. Run `resetpassword` in Terminal (available from Utilities → Terminal).
   3. Select your account from the drop-down list.
   4. Click the Reset button for **Reset Home Directory Permissions and ACLs**.

Comment: I can't copy the user folder because the internal hard drive is too small to have two user folders?